# R - How does t-test for significance of terms in GLM work?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, t-test

Let's have some generalized linear model and its summary:

```
Call:
glm(formula = time ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 2, raw = T) + poly(nDOF, 
    3, raw = T) + poly(ndoms, 3, raw = T) + I(1/nprocs):poly(ndoms, 
    2, raw = T), family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = dataFact)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.34009  -0.07888  -0.02411   0.05733   0.23354  

Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                          -3.570e+00  1.339e-01 -26.662  < 2e-16 ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2, raw = T)1        7.868e-01  6.659e-02  11.815  < 2e-16 ***
poly(I(1/nprocs), 2, raw = T)2        1.199e-01  2.355e-02   5.093 7.75e-07 ***
poly(nDOF, 3, raw = T)1               6.790e-04  1.340e-05  50.681  < 2e-16 ***
poly(nDOF, 3, raw = T)2              -5.341e-08  1.609e-09 -33.197  < 2e-16 ***
poly(nDOF, 3, raw = T)3               1.570e-12  5.819e-14  26.979  < 2e-16 ***
poly(ndoms, 3, raw = T)1              5.545e-03  7.238e-04   7.661 6.40e-13 ***
poly(ndoms, 3, raw = T)2             -4.723e-06  1.213e-06  -3.893 0.000132 ***
poly(ndoms, 3, raw = T)3              1.648e-09  5.936e-10   2.776 0.005985 ** 
I(1/nprocs):poly(ndoms, 2, raw = T)1 -1.402e-03  1.887e-04  -7.429 2.60e-12 ***
I(1/nprocs):poly(ndoms, 2, raw = T)2  6.675e-07  1.198e-07   5.570 7.65e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.01261502)

    Null deviance: 1916.0464  on 223  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:    2.6869  on 213  degrees of freedom
AIC: -331.13

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

I'm interested in the part `Coefficients`, where the results of t-tests for significance are listed. And my question is - how does the t-test work here?

Is it a [One-sample t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#One-sample_t-test)? In that case I think, that the predicted values by a model are the observations $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and their mean is $\mu_0$. And then I think, that for every term is testing done by removing the term, computing the mean of new predicted values and compared to the "reference mean" $\mu_0$.

Does it work it this way? I'm a beginner with statistics, so, I'd be glad if you could provide more detailed answers.

Comment: These are tests on the statistical significance of the regression coefficients.

Comment: @MichaelChernick They are, but I'm interested especially in this one which is native for [summary](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/summary.glm.html) function in R.

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me, & it has an upvoted & accepted answer. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The t-statistic in the R summary for glms is calculated by dividing the coefficient by the standard error:

```
t=coefficient_x / standard error_x
```

If I'm not mistaken this is the Wald test. The resulting p-value is then obtained from a t-distribution with degrees of freedom dependent on the amount of degrees of freedom used in the entire model and by the variable, and is given for a two-sided test.

*Of note: you can also see this in R by looking at the code for* `summary.glm` *(run* `summary.glm` *without the brackets* `()`*). Here you can see that the summary.glm function uses* `2*pt(-abs(tstatistic),df)` *where* `df` *is the residual degrees of freedom stated elsewhere in the summary output.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm just a little confused about the resulting p-value. When I to compute t-value, let's say $1.199e-01 / 2.355e-02 \approx 5.091295$, it is ok. But then, when I try to get p-value like this `pt(5.091295, 1)` I get the value 0.9382654 instead of  7.75e-07 which is in the table. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try 1- the value you find. R gives you the left hand side of the distribution

Comment: When I try that, I get $1 - 0.9382654 = 0.0617346$ which is still vastly different from  $7.75e-07$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the degrees of freedom I stated were wrong. As nprocs is entered in your model as factor and uses 2df (or so it seems), the df used for the t-test is 213 (amount of df for your model) +2 = 215. Then the p-value is two-sided, so the value you get from 1-pt(t,df) should be doubled. (I've edited this into the answer)

Comment: Ok... Could you, please, add this short example into your answer too, together with the information about DoF for single terms? (I mean, why exactly 2 here?)